# How to install driver for TP-Link TL-WN722N(EU)V2 on Ubuntu 17.04 Kylin

Tags: drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

I can not install the TP-LINK WN722N V2, which includes a 8188 EUS chip.
Then I tried to install the backports v4.4.2,but 
 do not want to recognize either.

The TP-Link driver installation errors thrown out:

```
man@kman-livve:~$ cd '/home/kman/Documents/Tplink 722 N V2/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.8_13968.20150417'
kman@kman-livve:~/Documents/Tplink ...$ sudo make

"******************************************"
"NO SKRC,we will use default KSRC"
"******************************************"
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.10.0-15-generic/build M=/home/kman/Documents/Tplink 722 N V2/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.8_13968.20150417  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-15-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:140: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '722'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-15-generic'
Makefile:1367: recipe for target 'modules' failed
```

A method to know him, I do not know about.
Thanks

Model:TL-WN722N(EU)_V2_161112_Linux.zip
Chipset:rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.8_13

http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/TL-WN722N.html#Driver

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I'm sorry but your question is completely unclear please review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and then [edit] your post so that we can understand. You may find [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) useful.

Comment: RTL8188EUS is supported - just works - in 16.04. Use an alternative connection and make sure the OS is fully updated.

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `rfkill list all; lsusb`

Comment: lsusb
[https://s11.postimg.org/651nvx24z/Screenshot_from_2017-04-07_13-42-18.png(lsusb) Bus 004 Device 003: ID 2357:010c

Comment: I am having the a similar problem. I am also trying to install a TL-WN722n V2 (EU) wireless adapter in 16.04 LTS. I downloaded the file and the install process put out the following: [Install Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWqKB.png) Also the output of lsusb is: ID 2357:010c and lsusb -t gives no further driver info. I have yet to be able to plug the adapter in and get the green light to turn on

Comment: I know this is old, but I strongly suggest this one: https://github.com/quickreflex/rtl8188eus

Comment: Ubuntu Kylin 17.4 reached end of public support in January of 2018, and as per https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic this query if off topic here.

Comment: @K7AAY Though 17.04 reached EOL in January 2018, but since the question was asked when 17.04 was supported, it can't be considered as off-topic. Considering views and votes, it's neither worth closing.

Answer (score 6):

for version 2 the driver provided on official website don't work it has chip-set of RTL8188 so install "lwfinger" drivers

step:1 make a temporary directory

```
$ mkdir tmp
```

step:2 move to temporary directory

```
$ cd tmp
```

step:3 clone driver repository

`$ git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu.git`

step:4 change directory of cloned repo !

`$ cd rtl8188eu`

step:5 make the driver for your system (Note: you should have kernal headers to make, google it !)

```
$ make all
```

step:6 after successful make

```
$ sudo make install
```

step:7 reboot your system

```
$ sudo reboot
```

after rebooting you will see the notification light turning on. have a nice day :)

edit: 10/03/2018

As @BradHein suggested step 7 isn't required , just plug out and plug in the adapter again!

Comment: This is the best answer however as a die hard Linux fan I try to avoid reboots at all cost. In this case, simply unplugging and plugging in the USB Wi-Fi device is sufficient :)

Answer (score 4):

Your folder name has spaces in it that make it impossible to compile with make.  Remove the spaces and it should compile.
Your folder is named `/home/kman/Documents/Tplink 722 N V2/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.8_13968.20150417` and that is why you see the error `** No rule to make target '722'.` as make expects the first thing after the space to be something defined in the Makefile such as modules or install

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to lwfinger driver I had a problem to use it as access point. So I have ported original TP-Link driver to work with kernel 4.9.

I have tested it on kali but I assume you will have no problems to use it with ubuntu:
https://github.com/mfruba/kernel/tree/master/drivers/TL-WN722N_v2.0-Ralink