# Driver Installation for TP Link WN722N (EU) V2 does not work

Tags: drivers, wireless, dkms, tp-link

I am currently trying to install the Driver from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu.git
I tried it with the dkms installation via:

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8188eu
sudo dkms install 8188eu/1.0
sudo modprobe 8188eu
```

Did not work, so i removed the driver from dkms. After that i tried this:

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu.git
cd rtl8188eu
make all
sudo make install
sudo reboot
```

Output: $ lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0409:005a NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 24f0:0137  
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 2357:010c  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

output: $ sudo lshw -C network

```
  *-network
       Beschreibung: Ethernet interface
       Produkt: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       Hersteller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:03:00.0
       Logischer Name: enp3s0
       Version: 11
       Seriennummer: 70:85:c2:AA:AA:AA
       Größe: 10Mbit/s
       Kapazität: 1Gbit/s
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       Konfiguration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       Ressourcen: irq:27 ioport:d000(Größe=256) memory:f0904000-f0904fff memory:f0900000-f0903fff
  *-network DEAKTIVIERT
       Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung
       Physische ID: 1
       Bus-Informationen: usb@3:10
       Logischer Name: wlxc025e919795e
       Seriennummer: c0:25:e9:19:BB:AA
       Fähigkeiten: ethernet physical wireless
       Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
```

output: ifconfig

```
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 70:8B:c2:AA:AA:AA  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Lokale Schleife  
          inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
          inet6-Adresse: ::1/128 Gültigkeitsbereich:Maschine
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:2908 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:2908 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:215464 (215.4 KB)  TX-Bytes:215464 (215.4 KB)
```

output: dkms status
no output.

Both Versions executed with no errors. But the TPLink can not be determined by Xubuntu. I am installing on a new Xubuntu installation.

This does not work for me: [How to install driver for TP-Link TL-WN722N(EU)V2 on Ubuntu 17.04 Kylin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900783/how-to-install-driver-for-tp-link-tl-wn722neuv2-on-ubuntu-17-04-kylin)

What i am doing wrong?
EDIT: I added some output information.

EDIT: Added more output information.
lsmod | grep 8188

`8188eu                720896  0`

dmesg | grep 8188

`[    3.413516] 8188eu: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    3.413748] 8188eu: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    3.414812] Chip Version Info: CHIP_8188E_Normal_Chip_TSMC_D_CUT_1T1R_RomVer(0)
[    3.436788] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8188eu
[    3.438585] r8188eu 3-10:1.0 wlxc025e919795e: renamed from wlan0`

edit:
I tried that:

`sudo ifconfig wlxc025e919795e up`

to enable that wlan. Very Strange name by the way. But this must be my wlanusb device. 
After that i scanned the network and found my accespoints:

`sudo iwlist wlxc025e919795e scan`

gives me the available access points. 
Then i connect to one accces point by the hardware adress of the accespoint:

`sudo iwconfig wlxc025e919795e ap AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF key off`

after that. i execute ifconfig. and i get an ipv6 adress. I also would get an ipv4 adress. On my apple macbook i get an ipv4 and a ipv6 adress from the router. My Networkmanager shows me that i have still no internet connection. But i can ping the router with ping6.

`ping6 -I wlxc025e919795e fe80::c225:and:the:rest:of:the:ipv6:adress`

The router responds and i get a signal. Iam unable to ping google.com or a other server because iam in an captive portal network from the Telekom. and i have to send an http request from my firefox browser for example to get to the login page. My webserver says that the website is not found. Looks like that firefox thinks that iam not connected to the router. XFCE says that a wlan does not exist. Maybee i have to rename wlxc025e919795e to wlan0 but how? And why is that so complicated and doesn't work?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: lsusb

Comment: yeah i added lsusb and some more. So lshw -C network also give me driver=r8188eu but i seems that this device is deactivated. i have to turn it on but how?

Comment: Hmmmm. Is the hardware switch set to disable wireless? `rfkill list all`

Comment: rfkill list all
or
sudo rfkill list all
gives me absolut no output

Comment: Please show us: `lsmod | grep 8188` and also: `dmesg | grep 8188`

Comment: ok. i added the output of your commands to my text.

Comment: And i added some more that i found out that is interessting

Comment: Why did you attempt to connect with iwconfig and not Network Manager??

Comment: I dont know how to connect with the network manager. How can i connect with the network manager?

Comment: Click the icon at the upper right, see your network listed, click on it and connect. https://www.eui.eu/Images-2011/ServicesAdmin/ComputingService/eduroam/eduroamUbuntu(1).png

Comment: i gave up. I bought a wifi stick that works out of the box with linux.