# TP-Link TL-WN722N v2 Driver Problem Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, tp-link

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu so sorry if I'm missing something obvious. I've successfully compiled and installed https://github.com/clnhub/rtl8192eu-linux.git without errors.

```
$ sudo make install

install -p -m 644 8192eu.ko  /lib/modules/5.8.0-43-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/

/sbin/depmod -a 5.8.0-43-generic
```

But I don't see any mention of wireless devices etc in settings->network or or in the top right hand corner of the desktop. The device is plugged in and shows up with lsusb:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2357:010e TP-Link TL-WN722N v2
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04d9:1603 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 145f:02b5 Trust Trust Wireless Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I've tried restarting the computer and also restarting the network-manager. Have I missed a step? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: keyboard and mouse are plugged into adjacent usb slots and they work fine, but is it possible it's the usb drivers?

Comment: It is that it is the *wrong* USB driver! Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2357:010e TP-Link TL-WN722N v2

Please run the terminal command:

```
modinfo 8192eu | grep 010E
```

It should return blank. This driver doesn't actually cover your device.

Please instead use this driver: https://github.com/morrownr/8812au

I have verified that it indeed does cover your device:

```
modinfo 8812au.ko | grep 010E
alias:          usb:v2357p010Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
```

Complete dkms installation instructions are included in the README. Feel free to post back if you get stuck or have further questions.

Comment: thank you so much that's done the trick! To be honest though, I'm still left confused - This device supposedly has the RTL8188EUS chipset rather than the RTL8812AU? http://en.techinfodepot.shoutwiki.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN722N_v2  & https://askubuntu.com/questions/900783/how-to-install-driver-for-tp-link-tl-wn722neuv2-on-ubuntu-17-04-kylin

Comment: Not every version of any driver covers every usb.id, especially if the driver wasn't updated with later usb.ids after new devices were manufactured and shipped. We can actaully see the supported usb.ids in the code in *os_dep/linux/usb_intf.c*.  Additionally, I suggested morrownr's version because it compiles very cleanly with no warnings on my 5.11 system.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for your help!

Comment: hi, this was working for me for a while, but recently the driver started uninstalling itself everytime I restart the computer. I can reinstall it successfully but the wireless wont work until I restart the computer, at which point the driver uninstalls! Any ideas? Thanks.